# Pandas Multiindex with one column not having multiple levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a complex MultiIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
metrics = ['PT', 'TF', 'AF']
n_replicates = 3
n_nodes = 6
cols = [(r,m,n) for r in range(n_replicates) for m in metrics for n in range(n_nodes)]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols,names = ['Replicates', 'Metrics', 'Nodes'])

ind = range(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=ind)
df.sortlevel(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

And it's giving me some problems. One of them is: I would like to add a column that doesn't have all the levels of the MultiIndex:

```
df[r, 'Graph'] = ....
```

However, I ultimately end up needing to make:

```
df[r, 'Graph', 0] = ....
```

And when I reference that column I also need to use `df[r, 'Graph', 0]`, which is clunky since there's not actually anything happening on that third level. Is there a way around this?

Edit: more examples

Adding the column:
    df[0,'Graph'] = arange(5)
    ValueError: invalid entry

```
df.ix[:,[0,'Graph']] = arange(5)
KeyError: "['Graph'] not in index"

df.xs[0,'Graph'] = arange(5)
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object does not support item assignment

df[0, 'Graph', 0] = arange(5) #Works! But I have to reference a lower level that doesn't mean anything for this 'Graph' column.
```

Reading from the column:
    df.ix[:, [0,'Graph']] #Gives the whole of df[0], not just the [0,'Graph'] column

```
df[0, 'Graph']
KeyError: 'MultiIndex lexsort depth 0, key was length 2'

df.sortlevel(level=0, axis=1, inplace=True)
df[0, 'Graph'] #Works! Though if one is making many manipulations to the dataframe then this sortlevel needs to be called a lot.
```

Further edit from Jeff's second comment:
I appreciate a given column needing to have all the levels of the multiindex. I have thought about just having another frame, though I would like to keep the data all together in one unit, for storing in HDF5s, etc. The answer for this would be panel. However, I will ultimately have several levels above this one, and I'm leery of panels of panels of panels, if that's even possible. I'm definitely open to other angles of attack that I haven't thought about that obviate all these issues.

Comment: for this and your other questions, pls look at the docs: [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex), you need to use ``ix/loc`` or ``xs``

Comment: I appreciate those docs, and have looked at them closely many times. However, that particular page is largely oriented at not MultiIndexes, and so most of the examples aren't geared towards them. So when I'm trying to do odder/more complex MultiIndex, I have not found examples that give me a lot of clarity. This is what is leading me to ask my question. I will edit my question to give more clarity of what I've been trying.

Comment: you cannot add a column that doesn't have all the levels of a multi-index. best to keep it in another frame then join/index as needed. Maybe give a complete toy example and we can provide more help. Its not clear what you are trying to do.